# How to dynamically concatenate form results

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I've got a workbook with two sheets. Sheet 1 is linked to a Google form with something like the following:

```
timestamp | fruit | rating
```

On sheet 2 I want to be able to concatenate the fruit and rating together as results come in, so something like:

```
Apple_5  
Pear_1  
etc
```

Is there a way to automate this? I've been trying to figure out how to combine concatenate with things like import range, filter, etc, but to no avail.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(filter(CONCAT(info!B2:B&"_",info!C2:C),CONCAT(info!B2:B&"_",info!C2:C)<>"_"))
```

(where `info` is your responses sheet and values are at columns `B` and `C`)

Comment: Not sure I understand how, but that did it. Thanks @marikamitsos! I clearly have to learn more about how to work with arrays :)

Comment: Glad it worked for you :). Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C="",,B2:B&"_"&C2:C))
```

[image: 0]